# @EventListener annotated method with non-void return value doesn't trigger a new event

Tags: java, spring-boot, events

I've got a following method in which I am attemping to return a none void type and hoping to handle the published event by the same method (recursively).:

```
@EventListener
@Async

public GenericSpringEvent<?> onGenericEvent(GenericSpringEvent<?> event) throws InterruptedException {

Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Received spring generic event - " + event.getWhat() + ", thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
return new GenericSpringEvent<String>(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), true);
}
```

The method is innitially triggered by the following call within my application:

```
GenericSpringEvent<String> genericSpringEvent = new GenericSpringEvent<>("GENERIC - STRING - TRUE", true);
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(genericSpringEvent);
```

the listener is called only once. I would expect an endless loop instead. Can someone explain me how to achieve it. It doesn't have to be the same listener method though, I would like to understand how this non-void return feature works. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are publishing the GenericSpringEvent only once! that is the reason.
In order to publish it again, I see two options to do it:

1 - you have to do the same: `applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(genericSpringEvent);` in your onGenericEvent method

2 - write some aspect around your onGenericEvent method so that after return you do `applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(returnedGenericSpringEvent);`

Returning the event doesn't make it published, the method annotated with @EventListener is just like any other method so that's why it may have a non-void return.

Comment: in this document https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2
they say that: 
"You can define a non-void return type for any method annotated with @EventListener. If you return a non null value as the result of the processing of a particular event, we’ll send that result as a new event for you."

I was alreeady aware of two solutions you gave. Or did I misunderstand what the citated blog said?

Comment: hmm.. maybe it has something to do with type erasure in Java, try a non-generic class.. let us know if that works :) btw are you sure of the spring version you are using..

Comment: I tried it wit a non generic class and it doesn't work. The listener is only called once. I also tried to change the return type to String hoping the framework will somehow wrap it into the Event type from the method signature (but how? the event takes another boolean param as well) which didn't work neither.

Comment: I think the reason is it is @Async.. so you have to return a Future of GenericSpringEvent<String>. so try to return AsyncResult<GenericSpringEvent> instead, and let us know if that works :)

Comment: I used the AsyncResult... as the return value but then I got this exception:
` java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask cannot be cast to org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult at com.moor.events.CustomListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8cafbf6.onGenericEvent(<generated>) `

Comment: but, without @Async it works:  
`Publishing custom event. , thread id 73  
Received spring generic event - GENERIC - STRING - TRUE, thread id 73  
Received spring generic event - 1554132199678, thread id 73  
Received spring generic event - 1554132204680, thread id 73  
Received spring generic event - 1554132209684, thread id 73`  

I would still like to make it work in an asynchronous manner

Comment: I was able to eliminate the exception. Nevertheless the listener still gets only the first initial call from the triggering publisher

Comment: You used the AsyncResult as the return type .. ? No, use the Future<GenericSpringEvent<?>> instead

Comment: that was mistakenly done so by autocomplition hence the exception. I corrected it two comments ago to the Future<GenericSpringEvent<?>>. But as I have already said the event is only fired up once - from the initial publisher method call. I set a breakpoint within the AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent() but it never gets called when the listener return after the first time.

Comment: could you provide the code of the method after your changes (returning Future) ?

Comment: sure!
    `@EventListener
    @Async
    public Future<GenericSpringEvent<?>> onGenericEvent(GenericSpringEvent<?> event) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Received spring generic event - " + event.getWhat() + ", thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return AsyncResult.forValue(new GenericSpringEvent<>(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), true));
    }`

Comment: yeah.. i reproduced your example and it seems not working, I googled it now and it seems it is an issue/not implemented yet. and the issue is open, you can check it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21831

Answer (score -1):

it works in this way

```
@Async
@EventListener
public CompletableFuture<ResponseDTO> generateXml(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    logger.debug("First step completed");
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> ResponseDTO.builder()
            .build());
}

@Async
@EventListener
public void sendXml(ResponseDTO responseDTO) {
    logger.debug("Second step completed");
}
```

Enjoy